# Can a Paladin take levels of other classes?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

In 3.5 D&D, [paladins](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/paladin.htm) have severe restrictions on multiclassing:

> Like a member of any other class, a paladin may be a multiclass character, but multiclass paladins face a special restriction. A paladin who gains a level in any class other than paladin may never again raise her paladin level, though she retains all her paladin abilities.

Because Pathfinder is based on 3.5 D&D, **do Pathfinder paladins face the same restriction?** That is, if a Paladin multiclasses to say, a fighter, can she take another level of Paladin later on?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Pathfinder has removed that restriction.

The Pathfinder paladin's [entry on Ex-Paladins](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin#TOC-Ex-Paladins) is a direct copy-paste of the first paragraph of [the corresponding D&D 3.5 entry](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/paladin.htm), with minor vocabulary adjustment. The 3.5 entry includes a second paragraph about the multiclassing restriction quoted in the question above, and the Pathfinder entry does not.

A quick search through the rest of the Pathfinder paladin entry doesn't turn up any other mention of such a restriction (the word "multiclass" isn't used *once* in the entire entry). Thus, the restriction is removed.